# C++ biginteger class operator=

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to implement a biginteger class, and after I created a biginteger class, with a proper header file, and at first I am trying to define a operator=() operator, so when I make a new biginteger object, I will be able to make it equals with a integer.

This is the main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bigint.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bigint bela = 15;
    cout << "Hello world!" << bela.mennyi() <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the biginteger header:

```
    #ifndef BIGINT_H
#define BIGINT_H

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class bigint
{
    public:
        bigint();
        void operator=(const int &a);
        int mennyi();

    protected:
    private:
        std::vector<int> numarray;
};

#endif // BIGINT_H
```

And the biginteger.cpp file:

```
#include "bigint.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


bigint::bigint()
{
    numarray.resize(0);
}

void bigint::operator=(const int &a)
{
    int b = a;
    if(b >= 0)
    {
        numarray.resize(0);
        while(b!=0){
        numarray.push_back(b%10);
            b = b/10;
        }
    }
}

int bigint::mennyi()
{
    int ki = 0;
    for(int i = (numarray.size())-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        ki = ki*10 + numarray[i];
    }
    return ki;
    }
```

When I start the debugging I get an error saying: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'bigint' requested.

Comment: you have only assignment operator, but not type conversion operator...
The compiler error message will lead you to the solution.
(you may also post it here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement this constructor:

```
bigint::bigint(int);
```

Comment: Note: `bigint bela = 15;` is no assignment, but a constructor call.